# How to prepare so many raster data into one ascii format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ascii

I have a number of spatial data on which I will like to perform an econometric analysis. The data include land use data, soil data, population data and so on which are all in raster format. I need to convert them into stata files to run the econometric model. I am confused on how to go about this. I need to prepare all the data in one ASCII text file for me to convert to stata files using another software. I need to prepare all the data as one sample, A guide on how to prepare the sample is in the image below. I do not know how to go about this.

[image: Data preparation]

Comment: It looks like Stata has tool to import from Excel.  There is a tool in ArcToolbox tool to convert a raster to an Ascii under Conversion tools.  Open the resulting Ascii file in a text editor and remove the header information.  Save the file.   Then open that file in Excel as a delimited text file. Save as Excel.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your comment. However, that is not what I want to get. I want to show each location/centroids with the corresponding variables. However, I have been able to get it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

My desired result is as shown in the image attached. I have been able to get it using the sample order in the arc  module.

[image: Desired result]